# On asymptotically uniformly distributed sequences in $(0,1)$.

Tags: measure-theory

A sequence $(x_k)_{k \in N}$  of real numbers from $(0,1)$ is called  asymptotically uniformly distributed  in $(0,1)$ if the condition
$$
\lim_{N \to \infty}\#(\{x_1, \cdots, x_N\} \cap [\frac{k}{N},\frac{k+1}{N}) )=1
$$
holds for each  natural number $k$, where $\#$  denotes counting measure.

**Question**. Let $\lambda$ be standard probability measure in $(0,1)^{\infty}$ and $D$ be a set of all  asymptotically uniformly distributed sequences in $(0,1)$.  Is the equality $\lambda(D)=1$ valid?

Comment: I don't understand how the condition of being asymptotically uniformly randomly distributed can ever be met because $\sum_k \#(\{x_1,\ldots,x_N\}\cap [k/N, (k+1)/N)) = N$, and so for an individual term of the sum to be $\sim N$ means that none of the others is.  Maybe you want to eliminate the $N$ from the denominator for a sensible definition?  Hope I'm not confused here.

Comment: @ForgotAlot  You are right. Here must be  $\lim_{N \to \infty}N \#(\{x_1, \cdots, x_{N}\}\cap [\frac{k}{N}, \frac{k+1}{N}))=1$.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @ForgotAlot   Sorry . There must be$\ lim_{N \to \infty}\#(\{x_1, \cdots, x_N\}∩[\frac{k}{N}, \frac{k+1}{N}))=1.$

Comment: Whatever this condition is, it is certainly not asymptotic uniform distribution, and it is certainly not satisfied for $\lambda$-random sequences. Maybe check the definition again?